# Find the centre and radius of $\arg{\left(\frac{z-(5+7i)}{z-(7+9i)}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

I'm having huge trouble trying to find the centre and radius of the circle that contains the segment $\arg{\left(\frac{z-(5+7i)}{z-(7+9i)}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

At first I tried to solve for the intersection of the two lines running from the centre to $(5,7)$ and $(7,9)$. That is, I tried to solve for the intersection of $(y-9)=m_1(x-7)$ and $(y-7)=m_2(x-5)$, but there are too many unknown variables so that didn't work.

Next I tried to find the cartesian equation to $\arg{\left(\frac{z-(5+7i)}{z-(7+9i)}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ by letting $z=x+iy$.

After substituting that in and realising the denominator I got $\arg{\left(\frac{(x-5)(x-7)-(y-7)(y-9)}{(x-7)^2+(y-9)^2}+i\frac{(x-5)(y-9)+(y-7)(x-7)}{(x-7)^2+(y-9)^2}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Which I think then means $\tan^{-1}{\left(\frac{(x-5)(y-9)+(y-7)(x-7)}{(x-5)(x-7)-(y-7)(y-9)}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Which gave the curve $(x-5)(y-9)+(y-7)(x-7)=(x-5)(x-7)-(y-7)(y-9)$, however when I plugged that into desmos I got a hyperbola with the minimum of the upper branch being $(7,9)$ and the max of the lower branch being $(5,7)$. So I've clearly done something wrong when finding the cartesian equation.

Nevertheless does anyone know the most efficient way to find the centre and radius? I'm not well versed in circle geometry theorems so maybe there is something there I have missed?

Comment: Remember: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I shouldn't have any problems with the quadrants right? Because both points are in the first quad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in simplifying the contents of the arg bracket.

The real part is $$\frac{(x-5)(x-7)+(y-7)(y-9)}{(x-7)^2+(y-9)^2}$$ and the imaginary part is $$\frac{(y-7)(x-7)\color{red}{-}(x-5)(y-9)}{(x-7)^2+(y-9)^2}$$

Since the arg is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ we can set these equal to each other and this leads to the equation of the circle $$(x-7)^2+(y-7)^2=4,$$

with the obvious conclusion.

The result can be arrived at very easily just by drawing a picture and no algebra (as has been indicated by others)

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is okay. Just recalculate carefully and you should be able to get the correct answer.

You can get the result by interpreting its geometric meaning without conducting tedious calculations.

Let us denote $Z(z), A(5+7i)$, and $B(7+9i)$. Since $\frac{z-(5+7i)}{z-(7+9i)} = \frac{5+7i-z}{7+9i-z}$, the given assumption is equivalent to $\angle BZA = \frac{\pi}{4}$. So by the inscribed angle theorem, $Z$ must be on the circle which has $AB$ as its chord.

There are two possible circles. Recall that $\arg$ is an "oriented" angle to determine the correct one.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further on "You can get the result by interpreting its geometric meaning without conducting tedious calculations." How could I find the centre without those calculations?

Comment: @Quippy Do you know what $\arg \frac{\alpha -z}{\beta -z}$ means geometrically?

Comment: Yes, I know it's a segment of a circle with end points at $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but I can't find the centre using any geometrical method that I know, could you perhaps detail some working to do this?

Comment: @Quippy Denote $O^\prime$ by the center of the circle. The inscribed angle theorem implies $\angle BO^\prime A = \frac{\pi}{2}$. I believe the rest should be not that complicated.